# Find duplicate batches based on multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains a series of related records (batches).  Each batch has a unique id and can contain customer payments.  I want to find if a batch is duplicate even if it is submitted on different days.

A batch can have 1 or more records.  Here is sample data set:

```
BatchId  InputAmount    CustomerName    BatchDate
-------  -----------    ------------    ----------
182944   $475.00        Barry Smith     16-Mar-2019
182944   $260.00        John Smith      16-Mar-2019
182944   $265.00        Jane Smith      16-Mar-2019
182944   $400.00        Sara Smith      16-Mar-2019
182944   $175.00        Andy Smith      16-Mar-2019
182945   $475.00        Barry Smith     16-Mar-2019
182945   $260.00        John Smith      16-Mar-2019
182945   $265.00        Jane Smith      16-Mar-2019
182945   $400.00        Sara Smith      16-Mar-2019
182945   $175.00        Andy Smith      16-Mar-2019
183194   $100.00        Paul Green      21-Mar-2019
183195   $100.00        Nancy Green     21-Mar-2019
183197   $150.00        John Brown      20-Mar-2019
183197   $210.00        Sarah Brown     20-Mar-2019
183198   $150.00        John Brown      21-Mar-2019
183198   $210.00        Sarah Brown     21-Mar-2019
183200   $125.00        John Doe        20-Mar-2019
183200   $110.00        Sarah Doe       20-Mar-2019
183202   $125.00        John Doe        21-Mar-2019
183202   $110.00        Sarah Doe       21-Mar-2019 
183202   $115.00        Paul Rudd       21-Mar-2019
```

Batches (182944, 182945) and (183197,183198) are duplicate while the other batches are not.

I thought maybe I could create a summary table with counts and sums and get close but I'm having trouble finding the true duplicates by including the names as well.

```
DECLARE @Summaries TABLE(
BatchId INT,
BatchDate DATETIME,
BatchCount INT,
BatchAmount MONEY)

-- Summarize the Data so we can look for duplicates
INSERT INTO @Summaries
SELECT a.BatchId, a.BatchDate, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount, SUM(a.InputAmount) AS BatchAmount 
FROM Batches a
WHERE a.BatchDate BETWEEN '20190316' and '20190321'
GROUP BY a.BatchId, a.BatchDate
ORDER BY a.BatchId DESC

-- find the potential duplicate batches based on the Counts and Sums
SELECT A.* FROM @Summaries A
INNER JOIN (SELECT BatchCount, BatchAmount, BatchDate  FROM @Summaries
            GROUP BY BatchCount, BatchAmount, BatchDate
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B
    ON A.BatchCount = B.BatchCount 
        AND A.BatchAmount = B.BatchAmount 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, a.BatchDate, b.BatchDate) BETWEEN -1 AND 1
```

Thank you for the help.  I'm using a SQL Server 2012 database.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
 with cte as

(select  BatchId  from table_name
group by BatchId  
having count(*)>1
) select * from table_name a where a.BatchId in (select BatchId   from cte)
```

Comment: I don't think that does what I want.  A duplicate batch would be defined as two or more batch id's that have the same number of records with the same amounts for the same customer names.  This looks like it just gives me duplicate batch id's which is not what I want.  The batch id is unique to a batch but not a unique key in this table.  It would be a foreign key.